# Какая разница(,) что он сделал?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Запятые нужны?

`Какая разница(,) что он сделал?`

`Какая разница(,) в какое время он пришел?`

`Какая разница(,) почему так произошло?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые нужны.

***Какая рАзница,** что он сделал?*

*Какая (вам) разница (в том), **что** он сделал?*

Это СПП  придаточным **изъяснительным**, указательное слово опущено. ***ЧТО*** — союзное слово.

Вопросительной является **первая часть** предложения.